# Storing unstructured excel data from different customer into database

Tags: excel

I have a set of product and its detail excel sheets provided by different csutomer.The coulmns inside the excel may vary from customer to customer.There may be more columns or the column name is different for different customer. I need to bring all these into a generalized structure and then store it in the database.Creating a mapping is tough since there are more than 50 customers and it grows.Is there any way to make use of Nosql DB.Please suggest what is the best method to do

Answer (score 0):

At first try to eliminate the cause of this diffrent structures. If you dont, you will have this Problem in future more and more.
Try to find a unique structure which allow each custom to add own needed fields, but all use the same core structure. Maybe this will not work by 100% but it will reduce your effort. The most People are open to suggetion like this and will friendly cooperate. With some you will have more effort, they wont accept give structure. How to handle this depends on your relationship to this customers.

Comment: Ya in Future we could try to do that.But as of now.We need something immediate to do in order to deliver.

Comment: ist difficult to advise. But i can tell you what i would do:  As short-term-solution (and quick-and-dirthy) i would make an Excel-makro to allign and sort all columns based on their names. Means this macro will open all files from the custom, copy the content and insert into one file. There it will rearrange all columns in the same order. Then copy all tabels into one and you have the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

For some problems like these, it helps to take **a non-technical approach**.

Talk to your boss/manager about creating a template for your customers to use, and send in the data. This will keep data in a consistent format. Your manager can help you engage your customers in pitching this idea.

Customers might often derive the next week's sheet of data from the previous week's. So, there might be a one-time activity of getting their old sheet into your new template. **Offer to assist them with this too** (its a one-off activity per customer).

If there is management buy-in for such an approach, it will help streamline things much better.

The **alternative is to set up a technical integration/transformation process**, but that will require significant up-front effort to identify different cases/variations, and adding code/error handling to handle those cases. Not to mention the ongoing support that might be required for each execution of that integration process.

Naturally, the cost vs. benefit of either approach will vary based on factors like frequency of how often your customers send in files, etc. If its once a year, then a manual approach is fine. If its weekly, its best to either go down the template route, or set up an automated integration/transformation process.

Comment: thanks  Phylp for the feedback.As you told  in the long run we can go with the approach of creating template.But as of now its not possible.I will check for the possibilities of technical integration and transformation.Is there any advantage in using Nosql DB to store these unstructured data,because the client required to know about its possibility.Or do we have any disadvantage in using NoSql.

Comment: If you're looking for an immediate/near-term solution, then throwing an unknown (to you) technology like NoSQL isn't going to solve the problem soon, given the learning curve involved. Secondly, you'd need to see what sort of data you're looking to store. Is this something like price information, or other such measurable data? If so, then structured data is probably the preferable approach. If its unstructured/textual data, then yes, you can consider NoSQL as an option.